# Does iowaitnotify close_wait guarantee the file is written completely?

Tags: linux, filesystems

Please clarify if `close_write` event of ionotifywait will guarantee that the file has been completely written.

The situation is a file transfer program will send a file X to a remote server Z and need to move the X when the file is completely transferred by monitoring the X on Z. We do not know when the transfer happens, hence need to monitor.

[bash script inotifywait wait for file completely written before proceding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46542819/bash-script-inotifywait-wait-for-file-completely-written-before-proceding) indicates that `close_write` tells file being completely written.

> What would be the best way to check if both files are **completely written**

> As pointed out by pacholik close_write as event option alone is sufficient:
>
> ```
> inotifywait -m -e close_write $1 | while read line
> ```

However, the man page says **does not necessarily imply the file was written to**.

[inotifywatch(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywatch)

> close_write
> A watched file or a file within a watched directory was closed, after being opened in writeable mode. This does **not necessarily imply the file was written to**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last paragraph highlights the fact that the `close_write` event only indicates that a file descriptor was closed, and that it was opened in writeable mode; it doesn’t say anything about what happened between the open and close events. Thus a process doing

```c
fd = open("/path/to/foo", O_RDWR);
close(fd);
```

will trigger a `close_write` event.

Essentially, if you wanted to know that a file was modified and the modifications were finished, you’d have to watch for both the `modify` and `close_write` (or `close`) events.

In your scenario, `close_write` is sufficient: once a file is closed, any subsequent read from it will produce all the data that was written to the file, and the original process modifying it can no longer do so (without re-opening it). This *doesn’t* mean that all the data is on disk, it might still be in cache; but processes reading it will see all the data.